# SQL Management Studio: Week Number based on a Mon-Sun week

Tags: sql, date, week-number

How do I change the syntax      datepart(week,[Tran Date]) as WeekNum   to provide the week number based on a Mon-Sun week standard vs. Sun-Sat?

For example: I need Sun 2/13/2023 to report week number 6 and not week number 7.

I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a setting in SSMS:

https://database.guide/set-datefirst-set-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the DATEFORST to one see example

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
 
SELECT @@DATEFIRST AS 'First Day' 
  ,DATEPART(dw, SYSDATETIME()) AS 'Today'
    ,DATEPART(dw, '2023-02-19') AS 'Sunday';
```

| First Day | Today | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WV-uUtOl)